# Apache Kafka + Spark Integration (REST API is needed?)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Got some fundamental problems, hope someone can clear them up.

So I want to use Apache Kafka and Apache spark for my application. I have gone through numerous tutorials and got the basic idea of what it is and how it will work.

Use case :

Data will be generated from a mobile device(multiple devices, lets say 1000) at an interval of 40 sec and I need to process that data and add values to the database which in turn will be reflected back in a dashboard.

What I wanted to do is to use Apache Streams and make a post request from android itself and then those data will be processed by the spark application and that's it.

**Issues:**

- Apache Spark

I am following this tutorial to get it up and running.( Am using JAVA, not scala)
Link : https://www.santoshsrinivas.com/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-16-04/

After everything is done, I execute spark-shell and it start. I have also installed zookeeper and kafka on my server and I have started the Kafka in the background, so that's not an issue.

When I run `http://161.xxx.xxx.xxx:4040/jobs/` I get this page [image]

In all the tutorial which I have gone through, there is a page like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF1fN.png  but I don't get this. Is it that spark is not properly installed?

Now when I want to deploy a standalone jar to spark, (Using this link : http://data-scientist-in-training.blogspot.in/2015/03/apache-spark-cluster-deployment-part-1.html ) am able to run it.
i.e with the command : `spark-submit --class SimpleApp.SimpleApp --master spark://http://161.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077 --name "try" /opt/spark/bin/try-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` , I get the output.

Do I need to submit the application everytime if I want to use it?

This is my Program :

```
package SimpleApp;

/* SimpleApp.java */
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "/opt/spark/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    //System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/winutil");
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR"); // Don't want the INFO stuff
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

    long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
    }).count();

    long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
    }).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
    System.out.println("word count : "+logData.first());
    sc.stop();
  }
}
```

- Now how do I integrate Kafka into it?
- How to configure the app in such a way that it get executed everytime
  kafka receives a message?
- Moreover, do I need to make a REST API through which I need to send
  the data to kafka i.e the REST api will be used as producer?
  Something like spark Java framework? http://sparkjava.com/
- If yes, again the bottleneck will happen at REST api level i.e how
  many request it can handle or not because everywhere I read that
  Kafka has a very high throughput.
- Is the final structure going to be like SPARK JAVA -> KAFKA -> APACHE
  SPARK ?
- Lastly how to do I set up the development structure on my local
  device? I have kafka/apache spark installed. And am using Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well,

You are facing some problems to understand how Spark works with Kafka.

First let's understand somethings:

1. Kafka is a Stream process platform for low latency and high throughput. This will allow you to store and read lot's of data really fast.
2. Spark has two types of processing, Spark Batch and Spark Streaming. What you are studying is batch, for your problem I suggest you to see apache streaming.

What is Streaming?

Streaming is a way to transport and transform your data in real time or near real time. It will not be necessary to create a process that you need to call every 10 minutes or every 10 seconds. You will start the job and it will consume the source and will post in the sink.

Kafka is a passive platform, so Kafka can be a source or a sink of a stream process.

In your case, what I suggest is:

1. Create a streaming producer for your Kafka, you will read the log of your mobile application in your web server. So, you need to plug something at your web server to start the consumption of the data. What I suggest you is [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/)Is a really strong application for streaming, this is in Ruby but is really easy to use. If you want something more robust and more focused in BigData I suggest [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org) This is hard to work, that is not easy but you can create pipelines of data flow to transfer your information to your cluster. And something REALLY SIMPLE and that will solve your problem is [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org/).
2. Start your Kafka, you can use Docker to use it. This will hold your data for a period, and will allow you to take your data when you need really fast and with a lot of information. Please read the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/) to understand how it works.
3. Spark Streaming - That will not make sense to use a Kafka if you don't have a stream process, your solution of Rest to produce the data at Kafka is slow and if is batch doesn't make sense. So if you are writing as streaming, you should analyse as streaming too. I suggest you to read about Spark Streaming [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html). And how integrate the Spark with Kafka [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html).

So, as you asked:

Do I need a REST API?
The answer is No.

The architecture will be like this:

Web Server -> Fluentd -> Apache Kafka -> Spark Streaming -> Output

I hope that will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Helps a lot. In layman terms, you are suggesting that while making a post req, I just store it somewhere on server (using fluentd/Flume) and that will feed kafka and from there spark streaming will ingest those data and give the output? Will it enable a high throughput system? 1000 pings/sec?

Comment: Yes for both, Spark will use Kafka as Source and spark can give the output in a relational database. Spark has a really high throughput 1000 pings/sec is easy to solve. I have a spark streaming that handle 20k events per seccond with no issue. See here this presentation: https://spark-summit.org/eu-2015/events/spark-streaming-pushing-the-throughput-limits-the-reactive-way/

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement and see how is it working. What will be the configuration of the server which can handle 20k events per second?

Comment: In my case I have a Flume that take the data from an IBM MQ, this store the data at a Kafka with 4 brokers and 16 partitions. I have a Spark Streaming with 16 executors that support this.

Comment: Could you share some post on spark stream? I have my zookeeper running, kafka is up. I created a topic, started a producer on cmd, and a consumer on cmd. I can receive messages on cmd, but how to receive them on spark? Any document will help a lot.

Comment: Here https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html