# How to integrate Spark and Kafka for direct stream

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am having difficulties creating a basic spark streaming application.

Right now, am trying it on my local machine.

I have done following setup.

-Setup Zookeeper

-Setup Kafka ( Version : kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1)

-Created a topic using below command

`kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

-Started producer and consumer on two different cmd terminals using below commands

Producer :

`kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test`

Consumer :

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test`

Now I can receive the data which I enter in the producer terminal in consumer console.

Now am trying to integrate Kafka into Apache Spark streaming.

Below is a sample code which I referenced from official documents. [Kafka & Spark Setup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#linking) and [Kafka & Spark Integration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

```
public class KafkaStreamingTry {
    static Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, StreamingQueryException {
        // Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Sampleapp");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(10));

        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "0");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest"); // from-beginning?
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("test");

        final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        jssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );


        System.out.println("Direct Stream created? ");
        stream.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("record key : "+record.key()+" value is : "+record.value());
                        return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                    }
                });

        System.out.println("Reached the end.");
    }
}
```

If I run this program, following is the log.

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51332:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\IdeaProjects\sparktest\target\classes;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-streaming_2.10\2.1.0\spark-streaming_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-tags_2.10\2.1.0\spark-tags_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\scalatest\scalatest_2.10\2.2.6\scalatest_2.10-2.2.6.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\spark\unused\1.0.0\unused-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.10\2.1.0\spark-core_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-mapred\1.7.7\avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.7\avro-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill_2.10\0.8.0\chill_2.10-0.8.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\kryo-shaded\3.0.3\kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\minlog\1.3.0\minlog-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill-java\0.8.0\chill-java-0.8.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.4\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-client\2.2.0\hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.2.0\hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.1\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\xmlenc\xmlenc\0.52\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.1\commons-io-2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.5\commons-lang-2.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-auth\2.2.0\hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.4.1\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.0\xz-1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs\2.2.0\hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-client\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-server-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-annotations\2.2.0\hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-launcher_2.10\2.1.0\spark-launcher_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-common_2.10\2.1.0\spark-network-common_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\leveldbjni\leveldbjni-all\1.8\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.5\jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.10\2.1.0\spark-network-shuffle_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-unsafe_2.10\2.1.0\spark-unsafe_2.10-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jets3t\jets3t\0.7.1\jets3t-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-recipes\2.4.0\curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-framework\2.4.0\curator-framework-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-client\2.4.0\curator-client-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0.1\guava-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.4.1\commons-math3-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.16\slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.16\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.16\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.16\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.3\compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2.6\snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\roaringbitmap\RoaringBitmap\0.5.11\RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\2.2\commons-net-2.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-jackson_2.10\3.2.11\json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.11.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-core_2.10\3.2.11\json4s-core_2.10-3.2.11.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-ast_2.10\3.2.11\json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.11.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.6\paranamer-2.6.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scalap\2.10.0\scalap-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.0\scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.22.2\jersey-client-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.4.0-b34\hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.4.0-b34\hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.4.0-b34\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.4.0-b34\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.4.0-b34\hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.22.2\jersey-common-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.22.2\jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-server\2.22.2\jersey-server-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.22.2\jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet-core\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.42.Final\netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.8.0.Final\netty-3.8.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\clearspring\analytics\stream\2.7.0\stream-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.1.2\metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.1.2\metrics-json-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-graphite\3.1.2\metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.5\jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.5\jackson-core-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-scala_2.10\2.6.5\jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.10.6\scala-reflect-2.10.6.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-paranamer\2.6.5\jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\ivy\ivy\2.4.0\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\net\razorvine\pyrolite\4.13\pyrolite-4.13.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.10.4\py4j-0.10.4.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-crypto\1.0.0\commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.6\scala-library-2.10.6.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10\2.1.1\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka_2.10\0.10.2.1\kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-clients\0.10.2.1\kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\yammer\metrics\metrics-core\2.2.0\metrics-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\101tec\zkclient\0.10\zkclient-0.10.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.4.9\zookeeper-3.4.9.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sql_2.10\2.1.1\spark-sql_2.10-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\com\univocity\univocity-parsers\2.2.1\univocity-parsers-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sketch_2.10\2.1.1\spark-sketch_2.10-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-catalyst_2.10\2.1.1\spark-catalyst_2.10-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\janino\3.0.0\janino-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\commons-compiler\3.0.0\commons-compiler-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.5.3\antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-column\1.8.1\parquet-column-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-common\1.8.1\parquet-common-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-encoding\1.8.1\parquet-encoding-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-hadoop\1.8.1\parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-format\2.3.0-incubating\parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-jackson\1.8.1\parquet-jackson-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11\2.1.1\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\driftking9987\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-tags_2.11\2.1.1\spark-tags_2.11-2.1.1.jar" kafkatry
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    17/07/03 01:23:55 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
    17/07/03 01:23:55 WARN SparkContext: Support for Scala 2.10 is deprecated as of Spark 2.1.0
    17/07/03 01:23:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    17/07/03 01:23:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: driftking9987
    17/07/03 01:23:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: driftking9987
    17/07/03 01:23:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
    17/07/03 01:23:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
    17/07/03 01:23:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(driftking9987); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(driftking9987); groups with modify permissions: Set()
    17/07/03 01:23:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 51353.
    17/07/03 01:23:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
    17/07/03 01:23:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
    17/07/03 01:23:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
    17/07/03 01:23:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
    17/07/03 01:23:58 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\driftking9987\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-4535fb48-e3c2-4af7-a57a-c5c54c2d9ed1
    17/07/03 01:23:58 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 352.5 MB
    17/07/03 01:23:58 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
    17/07/03 01:23:58 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    17/07/03 01:23:58 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:4040
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 51374.
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.56.1:51374
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 51374, None)
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.56.1:51374 with 352.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 51374, None)
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 51374, None)
    17/07/03 01:23:59 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 51374, None)
    17/07/03 01:24:00 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding enable.auto.commit to false for executor
    17/07/03 01:24:00 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
    17/07/03 01:24:00 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-0
    17/07/03 01:24:00 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding receive.buffer.bytes to 65536 see KAFKA-3135
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4040
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
    17/07/03 01:24:00 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\driftking9987\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-cd270e2f-257c-4878-88b4-8f908d65f76a

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now if I add

```
jssc.start();// Start the computation
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

It gives below following error,

```
17/07/03 01:26:46 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:556)
    at KafkaStreamingTry.main(KafkaStreamingTry.java:74)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:556)
    at KafkaStreamingTry.main(KafkaStreamingTry.java:74)
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4040
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/07/03 01:26:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Which is obvious.

Can please tell me how can I make it run? My requirement is that whenever I enter any data in producer terminal, the java application should acknowledge it and atleast print it once. I will try to figure out the calculation part on the json which I will receive.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721579/apache-kafka-spark-integration-rest-api-is-needed) is a question which I asked before and trying to follow the suggested architecture.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cs</groupId>
    <artifactId>sparktest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--For kafka integgration-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating the direct stream with Kafka you create `JavaPairDStream`. Now you can iterate the `JavaPairDStream` and print the key and value of your Kafka messages.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> jPairDStream =  stream.mapToPair(
        new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
            }
        });

jPairDStream.foreachRDD(jPairRDD -> {
       jPairRDD.foreach(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("key="+rdd._1()+" value="+rdd._2());
        });
    });

jssc.start();            
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

The command you are using with `kafka-console-producer.bat` will produce message in which key will be null. In order to produce messages with both key and value on topic `test` use below command. Enter comma separated key and value in console like `key1,value1`

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=, --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Your pom file has different versions for spark artifacts. Make sure you use same version for all artifacts. You need following dependencies to run your program.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I made the above changes and now atleast it's not exiting. But I get `INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.2.1
INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : e89bffd6b2eff799
` I assume that it means kafka is running but when I write anything in producer terminal, nothing is happening in the program.

Comment: Streaming app generates continues log and you have to scroll and see the messages. Try to put more messages in kafka-console-producer.I have tested your code and it is working fine.

Comment: It must be me who is missing something but I did everything as mentioned above. I added 50 new messages in the producer terminal but still it's not printing anything.

Comment: Please also check your Kafka version. In the question you have posted Kafka version 0.9.0.1 and from your spark app log it looks like it is configured for 0.10.2.1.

Comment: I added the pom file in the question. I have both the version on my windows but I am starting the 0.9.0.1 version as 0.10.2.1 gives error while starting kafka server. Moreover, there were many dependencies error which I was getting while setting up the java application, above mentioned pom is the one which works.

Comment: You have conflicting dependencies in your pom file. I have updated my answer with required dependencies. Please use them and try.

Comment: Thanks abaghel. For anyone who stumble upon this question, please make sure that all the versions are compatible with each other. I lost a significant time because of this.

Answer (score 4):

I think that logs says everything you need :)

> IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute

What are output operations? For example:

- foreachRDD
- print
- saveAsHadoopFile
- and other. More you can get in this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams) to the documentation.

You must add some operation to your application, for example save `stream.mapToPair` to variable and then invoke foreachRDD on this variable or print() to show values

Comment: Can you tell me what should be the datatype of `stream.mapToPair` and how to perform output operation on that?

Answer (score 0):

for your code add a action may help

```
stream.print()
```

Have a try and wish you good luck

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not starting the stream using ssc.start()