# How can I start multiple consumers for a Kafka topic with multiple partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have recently started using spark and have to deal with a case where I need to consume multiple partitions of a Kafka topic in spark. How can I start multiple consumers ? Do I need to have multiple instances of same application running using same group id ? or is there any configuration I can make use of while starting application and it does that job internally?

Comment: Structured Streaming?

Comment: @thebluephantom yes.

Comment: When you use Spark direct streaming, it will handle reading from Kafka itself. So, you should not be concerned about it. Just try a sample code for Spark Direct Streaming and see what will happens. you can use these links too; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874873/how-to-integrate-spark-and-kafka-for-direct-stream https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2018/07/09/how-to-data-processing-apache-kafka-spark/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `--num-executors` and using more than one core per executor will make more than one consumer thread in Spark

Each consumer thread gets mapped to a single partition.

Make the total threads equal the total partitions to maximize distributed throughput